# Dealing with currency in PHP - decimal places & number_format()

Tags: php, number-formatting

I need to store numbers that represent currency amounts in 2dp to be output to the screen. The same number may be altered with mathematical functions after being formatted. I'm sure I remember having errors in the past as a result of the number formatted number being treated as a string, and the thousand separator being the cause of the problem, but the below script runs without errors.

Is PHP's loose data types saving the day here? Did something change in a relatively recent PHP version? If not, are there other circumstances where `number_format()` can still cause a mathematical function to fail because the number is a string?

```
echo round(1111123.2, 2); //included to demonstrate how it can't be used for this purpose
echo "<br />";
echo number_format(1111123.2, 2);
echo "<br />";
$num = number_format(1111123.2, 2);
echo number_format($num / 42, 2);

// output
1111123.2
1,111,123.20
0.02
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The same number may be altered with mathematical functions after being formatted

Never do this. It's bound to end in tears, for example when you format numbers with non-english decimal separators. Do the operations on the raw numeric value, then format immediately before outputting.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the auto type-casting done by PHP. As far as I understand this, PHP will be able to type-cast to numbers in most generic mathematical functions, though, still not explicitely sure on this.
The strings are converted to required variable types

Answer (score 0):

Well... The best thing is to store and calculate with "real" numbers (`float`, `double` or `int`) and use `number_format()` only for representation.
But if you need to calculate with figures which have been returned from `number_format()`, think about writing a function like

```
function unNumber_Format($str) {
   $search  = array(',', '$', '€');
   $replace = array('', '', '');

   return (double) str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}
```

and using it like

```
echo number_format(unNumber_Format($num) / 42, 2);
```

and you're just fine! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use number formatter class:

however it requires the intl extension enabled and php 5.3.0+.. (sudo apt-get install php5-intl)

```
$f = NumberFormatter::create("en-US",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($f->format(1111123.2));
$f = NumberFormatter::create("en-US",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$f->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL,"€");
var_dump($f->format(1111123.2));
$f = NumberFormatter::create("de_DE",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($f->formatCurrency(1111123.2,"EUR"));
$f = NumberFormatter::create("it_IT",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($f->formatCurrency(1111123.2,"USD"));
$f = NumberFormatter::create("sk_SK",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($f->formatCurrency(1111123.2,"USD"));
```

Returns:

```
string(13) "$1,111,123.20"
string(15) "€1,111,123.20"
string(17) "1.111.123,20 €"
string(17) "US$ 1.111.123,20"
string(19) "1 111 123,20 US$"
```

If your customers are from different countries, just store for them the locale, and they will get their predefined number.